# Python numba returned data types when calculating MSE

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, numba, mse

I am using numba to calculate MSE. The input are images which are ready as numpy arrays of uint8. Each element is 0-255.
When calculating the squared difference between two images the python function returns (expectedly) a uint8 result, but the same function when using numba returns int64.

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def test1(var_a: np.ndarray, var_b: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return var_a - var_b

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def test2(var_a: np.ndarray, var_b: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return (var_a - var_b) ** 2

def test3(var_a: np.ndarray, var_b: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return (var_a - var_b) ** 2

a = np.array([2, 2]).astype(np.uint8).reshape(2, 1)
b = np.array([255, 255]).astype(np.uint8).reshape(2, 1)

test1(a, b)  # output: array([[3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
test2(a, b)  # output: array([[64009, 64009]], dtype=int64)
test3(a, b)  # output: array([[9, 9]], dtype=uint8)
```

What's unclear to me is why the python-only code preserves the data-type while the numba-code adjusts the returned type to int64?
For my purpose, the numba result is ideal, but I don't understand why. I'm trying to avoid needing to .astype(int) all of my images, since this will eat a lot of RAM, when I'm only interested that the result of the subtraction be int (i.e., not unsigned).

So, why does numba "fixes" the datatype in test2()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numba is a JIT compiler that first uses **static type inference** to deduce the type of the variables and then compile the function before it can be called. This means all literals like integers are typed before running anything. Numba choose to set the type of integer literals to `int64` so to avoid overflows on 64-bit machines (and `int32` on 32-bit machines). This means `var_a - var_b` is evaluated as an array of uint8 as expected. `(var_a - var_b) ** 2` is like `var_tmp ** np.uin64(2)` where `var_tmp` is of type `uint8[:]`. In this case, The Numba type inference system needs to do a **type promotion** like in any statically typed language (eg. C/C++). Like most languages, Numba choose to do a relatively safe type promotion by casting the array to `int64` because `int64` include all the possible values of `uint8`. In practice, the type promotion can be quite unsafe un pathological cases: for example, when you mix uint64 values with int64 ones, the result can be a float64 with a large but more limited precision and no warning is raised. If you use `(var_a - var_b) ** np.uint8(2)`, then the output type is the one you expect (ie. `uint8`) because there is no type promotion.

Numpy uses **dynamic type inference**. Moreover, integers have a **variable length** in Python so their type has to be defined by Numpy at runtime (not by CPython which only define the generic variable-sized `int` type). Numpy can thus **adapt the type of integer literals based on their runtime value**. For example, `(np.uint8(7) * 1000_000).dtype` is of type `int32` on my machine, while `(np.uint8(7) * 100_000_000_000).dtype` is of type `int64` (because the type of the right-most integer literal is set to `int64` since it is too big for a 32-bit integer. This is something Numba cannot do because of JIT compilation [1]. Thus, the semantics is a bit different between Numba and Numpy. The type promotion should be the same though (so to get results as close to Numpy with Numba).

A good practice is to explicitly type arrays so to avoid sneaky overflow in both Numpy and Numba. Casting integers to specific types is generally not needed but it is also a good practice when the types are small and performance matters (eg. integer arithmetic with intended overflow like for hash computations).

Note you can do `your_function.inspect_types()` so to get additional information about the type inference (though it is not easy to read).

[1] In fact, it Numba could type integer literals based on their value, but not variables. The thing is it would be very unexpected for users to get different output types (and behaviour due to possible overflows) when users change literals to runtime variables.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the detailed reply. So to be sure I understand: numba will do type promotion and infer that the result of (var_a - var_b) ** 2 may overflow, and type it as int64, thus, the result would be type safe (assuming the input var_a and b are uint8)?

Comment: Is it possible to get it to be safe from overflow *without* numpy-casting var_a and var_b to larger int variables? the numpy .astype() will copy the entire array, which would be computationally expensive to do for a lot of arrays (I deal with images and the values are always 0-255 uint)

Comment: Numba do not specifically consider the overflow of this expression. It is just a general semantic rule to avoid them which often works. For Numpy, AFAIK this is not possible. There is maybe some convoluted way to do that with ufuncs though (because ufuncs are the only thing in Numpy to do conversion before applying operations AFAIK). Note the performance of ufunc is not great since the ufunc consider each item as a singleton array internally (for sake of maintainability so far).